# OpenSSH login via public key does not work

Tags: authentication, passwords, server, public-key, openssh

I'm trying an SSH auth via public key, which works for several machines, but one single machine keeps not accepting it.

First of all, the constellation:
The machine which tries to connect: **OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008**
The server: **OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013**

This is what happens:

```
user@client:/root> ssh -v server
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering public key: /home/nagios/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@server's password:
```

The **sshd_config** of the server:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# Disable legacy (protocol version 1) support in the server for new
# installations. In future the default will change to require explicit
# activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

**ssh_config** of the client:

```
#       $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.23 2007/06/08 04:40:40 pvalchev Exp $

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no

# If you do not trust your remote host (or its administrator), you
# should not forward X11 connections to your local X11-display for
# security reasons: Someone stealing the authentification data on the
# remote side (the "spoofed" X-server by the remote sshd) can read your
# keystrokes as you type, just like any other X11 client could do.
# Set this to "no" here for global effect or in your own ~/.ssh/config
# file if you want to have the remote X11 authentification data to
# expire after two minutes after remote login.
ForwardX11Trusted yes

#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
    Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable support for the deprecated 'gssapi' authentication
# mechanism to OpenSSH 3.8p1. The newer 'gssapi-with-mic' mechanism is included
# in this release. The use of 'gssapi' is deprecated due to the presence of
# potential man-in-the-middle attacks, which 'gssapi-with-mic' is not susceptible to.
#   GSSAPIEnableMITMAttack no

# This enables sending locale enviroment variables LC_* LANG, see ssh_config(5).
SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
```

I've also checked the permissions to the home, .ssh folders and the files.
The client:

```
user@client:/home> ls -l | grep user
drwx------ 11 user   user 4096 Feb  2 13:48 user
user@client:/home> cd user
user@client:~> ls -al | grep '.ssh'
drwx------  2 user user  4096 Feb  2 13:48 .ssh
user@client:~> cd .ssh
user@client:~/.ssh> ls -al
total 32
drwx------  2 user user   4096 Feb  2 13:48 .
drwx------ 11 user user   4096 Feb  2 13:48 ..
-rw-------  1 user user    672 May 10  2010 id_dsa
-rw-------  1 user user    609 May 10  2010 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------  1 user user  12823 Feb  2 17:06 known_hosts
```

The server:

```
[root@server home]# ls -l |grep user
drwx------. 4 user user 4096 May 27  2013 user
[root@server home]# cd user
[root@server user]# ls -al |grep '.ssh'
drwx------.  2 user user 4096 Feb  3 13:09 .ssh
[root@server user]# cd .ssh
[root@server .ssh]# ls -al
total 12
drwx------. 2 user user 4096 Feb  3 13:09 .
drwx------. 4 user user 4096 May 27  2013 ..
-rw-------. 1 user user  609 Feb  3 13:09 authorized_keys
```

So I have absolutely no idea why the server keeps asking me for a password. I also have set a password, and this one is working. But I need an auth without a password.

Anyone any idea? I wonder if that really is an incompatibility...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the server logs, check if you are using the correct key, run server in debug mode (`LogLevel DEBUG3`) and follow logs. It will tell you the reason for rejecting the key.

Comment: Can you tell me please, which log files I should check for such entries? MAybe they're there already. I'd like to prevent from restarting, since that's an operational server. Thasnks.

Answer (score 0):

The entire OpenSSL 0.9.8 release is out of support per [openssl.org](https://www.openssl.org/source/) as is the entire 1.0.0 version!

Also, 0.9.8h in particular is ancient - even your own log shows it's from 2008.  The latest 0.9.8 was 0.9.8zh, per [github's OpenSSL release page](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases).

You SHOULD upgrade to the latest 1.0.1 or 1.0.2, or the latest LibreSSL or PolarSSL.

You NEED to at bare minimum upgrade to 0.9.8zh to get [8 years of vulnerability fixes](https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html).

You also need to review your sshd_config settings; per the [openbsd documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5) RSAAuthentication is a Protocol 1 only option, and you've got it set on your Protocol 2 only server.  I just noticed that; you may have other strange configurations in either or both configs - review them both carefully, and compare your post-version-upgrade client ssh_config to working ssh_config files on other clients.

Comment: Thank you so far. Just to clarify: There are many servers where the pubkey auth is working. Only this single server does not accept. And the authorized_keys file is correct.

There's another server with the same versions and I can use pubkey for auth just fine. Even sshd_config is the same (I've commented out the three lines: RSA, PubKey and the one after). Confusing enough, it's even the same operating system.

By the way, I tried updating, but am not familar with YaST. The YaST online-updater found several patches, even for OpenSSL. But the version string didn't change, even after a restart.

Comment: Is the ssh_config the same between working and nonworking client with the same version string?  You'd need to update OpenSSH, not just OpenSSL, to get the version string to change - it might be a static linking (i.e. a version of OpenSSL baked into the OpenSSH).  Sounds like you need to move to a new server OR check the client's firewalls and network access.

Comment: Well, the client is the only one in use for this. It's a Nagios machine and is meant to connect via SSH to run check commands. That's why pubkey is needed, actually. So I don't have any other client to compare with. And as the one server is quite identical to the other, but one is not working, I wonder where I could take a further look. I'll try to find another machine and test pubkey from there, to check if that server doesn't accept public key in general. But if you have any idea where I could take a look, please let me know. Thanks!